# Как отправить файлы (4) из БД одним сообщением Aiogram

Tags: mysql, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Сейчас файлы отправляются одним сообщением каждое. Хотелось бы, чтобы они отправлялись одним сообщением вместе, либо были прикреплены к текстовому сообщению.

КОД ОТПРАВКИ СООБЩЕНИЯ:

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data and c.data.startswith('obsh_day'))
async def process_callback_kbobsh(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    code = callback_query.data[-1]
    if code.isdigit():
        code = int(code)
    if code == 1:
        user_id = callback_query.from_user.id
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, text='Идет загрузка.\nПодождите, пока загрузятся все файлы.', show_alert=True)
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, f'День №1\n\nСсылка на ютуб:https://youtu.be/')
        await bot.send_chat_action(user_id, ChatActions.UPLOAD_DOCUMENT)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await bot.send_document(user_id, obsh_day1_dz)
        await bot.send_document(user_id, obsh_day1_kz)
        await bot.send_document(user_id, obsh_day1_rt)
```

ЗАПИСЬ ФАЙЛОВ В ДБ: (загружаю специальным скриптом)

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()


class MediaIds(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Media ids'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    file_id = Column(String(255))
    filename = Column(String(255))
```

Comment: из Базы данных*

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод [sendMediaGroup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup), в aiogram это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```py
media_group = MediaGroup([obsh_day1_dz, obsh_day1_kz, obsh_day1_rt])
await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=user_id, media=media_group)
```

Comment: не работает. (или я кривой)

Comment: Ошибка какая? Как отправляете?

Comment: TypeError: Media must be an instance of InputMedia or dict, not str

Comment: Обновите код, добавьте значения этих переменных:
obsh_day1_dz, obsh_day1_kz, obsh_day1_rt, непонятно, как они у Вас объявляются

Comment: из другого файла, там объявлена переменная в которой указан айди файла в телеграме

Comment: https://aiogram-birdi7.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/media_group.html